# ASP.NET MVC 2: Is the Model kept up to date in the View?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm currently using jQuery to keep things up to date in the View as options are selected in my Form. But my Model reflects those form elements so I was starting to think: is it possible to keep the model elements up to date as they are changing?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/

Comment: @Darin, I'm trying to find out if the Model keeps up to date in the View as things are being changed. Instead of attaching jQuery events on buttons, searching for the value and then repopulating. If instead I can just access the Model directly as it updates...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout JS is your friend:

http://knockoutjs.com/

Edit: It helps you move your model to the client side so that your JS code can keep it up-to-date according to user interaction. From there on, you can simply move it back, ready-to-use, to the server side. It's one more thing to learn but in complex views, it removes complexity and avoids the separation of model management between client and server: Everything's now in the client.

So, all in all, you'll probably have a little more code but it will be far more easy to read and maintain.

Comment: It seems pretty cool... other than the fact that it's one more thing to learn and yet more code on top of what already seems a bit too heavy.